# how to display concatenation value of muliple buttons values in textfield in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[image]

As shown how do I enter my phone number through that keyboard.
I am trying but my method is overloading the previous button values.
So please can one help me how to do that...
I think we need to concatenate the buttons value. If I press button "1" the value in textfield should be "1", if I then press "2" the value in textfield should become "12".
everything works properly except these.
clear button it clears the textfield

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) 
{
 $scope.chandru = false;
 $scope.noinput = "";
 $scope.newNumber = true;
 $scope.cleartext = function()
  {
   $scope.noinput = "";
  };
 $scope.hideshow = function(id) 
  {
   $scope.chandru = true;
  };
 $scope.updateOutput = function(btn)
   {
      if($scope.noinput == "" || $scope.newNumber) {
        $scope.noinput = btn;
        $scope.newNumber = false;
      } else {
          $scope.noinput += String(btn);
      }
      
   };

       
});
```

```css
.mainform {
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
 
 
 margin-right: 300px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-left: 300px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
}
.Head {
 color: #4169E1;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #DC143C; 
 font-family: Righteous;
}

.inputprop {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 30px;
}
.classnumber {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 35px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.classClear {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 70px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.classOk {
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
}


#buttondesign {
 display: inline;
 border: 2px solid black;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.clearbutton {
 border: 2px solid black;
 width: 60px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.okbutton {
 border: 2px solid black;
 width: 50px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 5px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>My Task</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styele.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div class="mainform">   
  <h1 class="Head"> SignUp</h1>
  <div style="color: #4682b4; font-size: 20px;">
  <center>
   Enter mobile number:
         <select class="inputprop">
     <option value="IND(91)">IND(91)</option>
     <option value="PAK(92)">PAK(92)</option>
     <option value="SRL(93)">SRL(93)</option>
     <option value="NUL(92)">NUL(92)</option>
  </select> 
   <input class="inputprop"type="text" name="mobileno" value="{{noinput}}" 
   ng-model="noinput" placeholder="enter mobile number"/><br><br>
   Press OK to send OTP

  </center><br><br>
   <center><div ng-init="num=['1','2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']">
            <div style="display: inline;"ng-repeat="item in num">            
     <button id="buttondesign"  type="button"  name="namebutton"
      ng-click="updateOutput({{item}})">{{item}}</button>   
     </div>   
     <input class="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" ng-click="cleartext()"/>
     <input class="okbutton"type="button" value="OK" ng-click="hideshow('second')"/> 
    </div>
   </center>
   
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a `ng-click="buttonPressed(number)"` on each button.

```
 <button ng-click="buttonPressed(1)>1</button>
 <button ng-click="buttonPressed(2)>2</button>
 <button ng-click="buttonPressed(3)>3</button>
    ...
```

So when you press a button it call this function.

Then in your controller you declare this function like this

```
var pressed = [];
$scope.buttonPressed = function(number){
    pressed.push( number ) ;
    console.log(pressed);
    // to other stuff   
}
```

Comment: what ? did you try this ou found another way ?